Select data from one sheet to another based on date and other criteria, getting repeating results
I have a spreadsheet with multiple entries encompassing a variety of parameters. My query seems to be working a bit, but is creating a lot of duplicate entries that are not in the original data set.
My current formula is:
=INDEX(Pipeline!B1:B100,MATCH(1,IF(Combined!$K$1>=Pipeline!J1:J100,IF(Combined!$J$1<=Pipeline!J:J,IF(Combined!$L$1=Pipeline!E1:E100,1))),0))
J1 = today - 2 months (8/30/2024)
K1 = today + 3 months (1/30/2025)
L1 = APAC(geography)

Data set with filtered results - what I would expect to see (please ignore colors):

The results I am getting (just limited to first 2 columns for example purposes and data load):

Tried a few versions of VLOOKUP with criteria, but settled on the above formula, and it works to pull in the appropriate fields for each entry - so I'm getting the correct full row.
However, after an initial few rows, the results start repeating, almost seeming to fill in blanks for the rows that do not match the criteria. I focused on Title as that is unique, Potential Customer will intentionally have repeats.

Without knowing your source data it is pretty hard to help you. Reading [ask] and [repro] will help you to improve your question. Maybe this link will help you too: Stack Overflow question checklist.

The data source is an excel workbook. Not sure how to attach here, but happy to send if it would be helpful. Looking to copy data that matches criteria from one tab to another.

please edit your question. Post some sample data into your question. And, in addition to your formula that is NOT  creating the desired result, please describe what the logic is to arrive at the desired result. We have no clue what you want to look up or filter on.
